# Subscript out of range / listobject exists but not found

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I want to automatically add a row if the last row is filled of my listobject. But the listobject is not identified on the if statement, and when I set variable tbl to the listobject it says the subscript is out of range.

```
With Sheets("Ruimtelijst")
    lastRow = .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
End With
    For Row= 4 To lastRow
        With Sheets("Uitwendige scheidingen")
'Intersect is not working either.
            'If Not Intersect(Target, .ListObjects("Table_" & Row - 3)) Is Nothing Then
            Set tbl = .ListObjects("Table_" & Row - 3)
            'End If
         End With
    Next
```

code to add the listrows:(in another module)

```
Set tbl= .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Source:=.Range("F" & NextRow + 11 & ":G" & NextRow + 11), XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
tbl.Name = "Table " & Rij - 3
```

and as you can see. the listobject is added in excel:(GrondWand is the original table name, changed it to english for here)

[image: Listobject shown in excel]

I've tried:

- changing `Sheets("Uitwendige scheidingen")` to `Sheets(Sheet2)` (apparently Sheet2 doesn't exist)
- `Sheet2.ListObjects("table_1")` instead of `Sheet2.ListObjects("Table_" Row - 3)`
- Copied the table name in excel and pasted it in the `Set tbl = .ListObjects("Table_" & Row - 3)` line

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate what you are actually trying to do? I dont quite follow those snippets to be honest. Adding a row to a listobject should be as simple as ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").ListObjects("TableName").ListRows.Add respectivly. Also, in the first snippet, you are asking for "Table_X" and in the second for "Table X" so once with _ and once with a space. Not sure thats the issue tho. I'm sure I could help if I just understood! :)

Comment: If you add data to the next available row beneath a table the table should automatically extend to include it; so not really understanding your _"trying to add a row to a listobject if last row is filled"_ statement.

Comment: This will return data from the first column on the last row `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Count).Range(1)`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook for example if you have two tables underneath each other and for prettiness you have only one row free between them. Listrows.add then comes in handy. At least that was the reason I used it in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can adjust this to your needs? Again, I'm unsure what exactly you want so I wrote it as generic as I could.

```
Sub test()

    'Goes through all sheets
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        'And through all listobjects on those sheets.
    For j = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ListObjects.Count
            'Just for your info: to see names and references?
        Debug.Print "Sheet, Listobject number and its name: " & i & " " & j & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ListObjects(j).Name
            'Find the last row
        LastRowOfThisListObject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ListObjects(j).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
            'If that row (first column) is not empty then
        If Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ListObjects(j).Range(LastRowOfThisListObject, 1) Like "" Then
                'Add another empty row below
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ListObjects(j).ListRows.Add

                'If you also want to write to it go with this:
'            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ListObjects(j).ListRows.Add
'                .Range.ClearFormats
'                .Range(1, 1) = " "
'                .Range(1, 2) = " "
'                .Range(1, 3) = " "
'                etc.
'                Call OtherSub(.Range) '...for example
'            End With

        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Edit to answer a follow up.
This works for me:

```
Sub test2()

Set target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:D5")
'The table is in Range("B4:I15")
Row = 4

With Sheets(1)
If Not Intersect(target, .ListObjects("Tabelle" & Row - 3).Range) Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "test"
End If
End With

End Sub
```

PS: its really difficult to guess where you defined what with the limited code you showed. I just made a table and defined some range to test it. I think your error is the missing .range. Hope you can adjust this as needed

Comment: I found a fix. the listobjects didnt had proper names when I gaveit to them because the space converted to a _ but somehow when i added a _ to the name to set the listobject as variable it gave that error. however the intersect is stil not working. ` If Not Intersect(Target, Blad2.[table_] & Rij) Is Nothing Then` gives me the error that the type missmatches. how can i fix that?

Comment: add a .range after your table in the intersect. See edit in the answer.

Comment: my .range is the Target because my sub is ```Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)```

Comment: I meant that right now you are trying to find an intersection between a range (target) and a table. But you need to tell excel that it should take the range of the table. Imagine you did ".name" after your table. Then excel would try to intersect a range (target) with a name. Which makes no sense. So you just gotta tell excel that you would like it to intersect the .range of your listobject. like so: Sheets(1).ListObjects("name") **.Range** .

Comment: Thanks. that worked. but unfortunately I get the error whenever I try to add a listrow with